# Strange characters in my textfields in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to load a fresh page of textfields used for input. When I load the page with the code below : 3 out of 5 of my text fields are loaded with some odd looking characters:

```
<UITextfield jfdjf;jdkk;fk;a;kfd xx000323920 >> I made up some of what it says, but it starts the line with <UITextfield
```

any ideas why this would happen?

here is the code :

```
if (!self.addView) {
        self.addView = [[AddView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddView" bundle:nil];
    }
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.addView animated:YES];
```

Comment: You mean in the log window ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the actual output and not some made up stuff. It's perfectly normal that the `description` (that is the method that gets called when you use `%@` in a NSString format) of a UITextField starts with `<UITextField`. What output did you expect?

Comment: After a little bit more thinking: maybe you accidentally used `NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textField];` instead of `NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textField.text];` Note the `.text` in the latter call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not use the **description** of the textfield but its **text**

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textfield];
//OR
NSLog(@"%@", textField);
```

==> this is bad as it does call textfield.description (and a textfield's description is not the text itself

use the **text property** instead

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textfield.text];
//OR
NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
```

Comment: Thanks all ... I guess I wasn't clear, when I call my AddView, and push that onto the stack, I expect five text input fields ... 3 out of the five have weird characters in them already, that I have to clear if I want to add data to them. but that you for the repsonses... I do appreciate it.

Comment: I figured out the issue, I had set methods for all of the fields, I am didn't need them. Thanks all!!